# Return of Brownian motion to zero

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, random-walk, probability-limit-theorems

From chapter 4 of Bulinskiy & Shiryaev's [Theory of Random Processes](https://www.google.com/books/edition/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86/T0soDAAAQBAJ) (ISBN 5-9221-0335-0):

> [**Exercise 26**] Let $W = \{W_t, t \geqslant 0 \}$ be a $m$-dimensional Brownian motion, where $m \geqslant 3$. Prove that $\|W_t\| \to \infty$ b.s. for $t \to \infty$. Prove that with probability $1$ the process $W$ will not return to point $0$ in any finite time. Explain why for $m=1$ these statements are not true. What does the following result look like in case $m=2$?

---

**Solution:**

Let $W = \{W_t, t \geqslant 0 \}$ be a $m$-dimensional Brownian motion in $\Bbb R^m$. Consider the process

$$\|W_t\| = \left( W_1^2 + \dots + W_m^2 \right)^{\frac12} = |W_t|$$

I tried to see the probability limit $ \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \Bbb P \left( |W_t|^{-1} \right)$, it is equal to $0$. Therefore, $ \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}|W_t|^{-1} = 0 $ almost certainly. This means that almost certainly $|W_t| \to \infty$ for $t \to \infty$. Did I do the right thing?

Then I saw the idea where it was used that $|W_t|^{-1}$ is a super martingale, where $t \geqslant \delta > 0$, but I don't know how to prove it. And I also don't know what to do with special cases with $m=1$ and $m=2$.

Comment: I once attended a talk on this topic.  Allegedly, it is related to PDEs.  If I properly recall, an expert on PDEs in the audience mentioned something along the lines of "throw a pebble into a pond and it will produce multiple ripples, but detonate a grenade and it will be heard only once".

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo . This is about waves in 2d vs 3d. In fact it is true that they have very different behaviour. OPs question is about diffusion (heat convection) in various dimensions. It is also true that in low dimenions $1$ and $2$ BM is recurrent and in higher dimensions it is transient. It has to do with PDEs also. The proofs I believe are not very elementary though.

Comment: @Ann . These matters are discussed with some proofs in section 3.3.C of Karatzas & Shreve *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo try to follow this [link](https://docviewer.yandex.ru/view/1130000055406926/?page=3&*=T8F6mQQHc11P9eMnSfabmAFkmfZ7InVybCI6InlhLWRpc2stcHVibGljOi8vam04bHEraEdaN1phck1IN2tJOEdtREFKakpNc0VjSVBRZzNNR0tiWTZvem1rWkVLMTUvWkM0elZ3ZkZsZjRxVHEvSjZicG1SeU9Kb25UM1ZvWG5EYWc9PSIsInRpdGxlIjoiQnVsaW5za2l5X0FfVl9fU2hpcnlhZXZfQV9OX1Rlb3JpYV9zbHVjaGF5bnlraF9wcm90c2Vzc292LnBkZiIsIm5vaWZyYW1lIjpmYWxzZSwidWlkIjoiMTEzMDAwMDA1NTQwNjkyNiIsInRzIjoxNjUyODkzMjI2NjE2LCJ5dSI6Ijk1MDcwMjMwMDE2Mjk4ODc5OTEifQ%3D%3D)